# C# How to define event for dynamically created control?

Tags: c#, events, dynamic, controls

I have written a code that create buttons dynamically. The code works well, and create controls when I click on a button. Now the next task is, I want to define click event for these dynamically created controls. How can I do this ? Below is the code, Please modify this code and paste in a reply, so that I can understand easily.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // create controls dynamically on form
    int n = 4;
    private void btnDisplay_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button[] button = new Button[n];

        int previousButtonPositionY;
        int previousButtonHeight;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new Button();
            button[i].Name = "btnButton" + i;
            button[i].Text = "btnButton" + i;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                previousButtonPositionY = button[i - 1].Location.Y;
                previousButtonHeight = button[i - 1].Height;
            }
            else 
            {
                previousButtonPositionY = 50;
                previousButtonHeight = 0;
            }

            button[i].Location = new Point(0, previousButtonPositionY + previousButtonHeight);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(button[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have initialized your button you can add an onclick event to it with

```
button[i].Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
```

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for reply. How to unsubscribe from this event handler in a certain condition ?

Comment: button[i].Click -= new EventHandler(button_Click);